# When is mandatory send SIGINT programmatically?

Tags: kill, signals, sigint

I know the recommendable way to **terminate** a foreground process is through the `SIGTERM` signal, it because it gives the opportunity to the process itself to clean/release resources. This signal only can be generated/send through a command, it through any of the `kill` `pkill` `killall` commands - until here I am ok. Furthermore it is the **default** signal for these commands.

Now, I know the `SIGINT` signal **interrupts** a process. Therefore "similar" as *terminate*.

But I read the following answer (extract) from:

- [How does SIGINT relate to the other termination signals such as SIGTERM, SIGQUIT and SIGKILL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047975/3665178)

> `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` are intended **specifically** for *requests from the terminal*: particular input characters can be assigned to generate these signals (depending on the terminal control settings). The default action for `SIGINT` is the same sort of process termination as the default action for `SIGTERM` and the unchangeable action for `SIGKILL`;

Until here according with the answer `SIGINT` is triggered by keys combination (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) **and** *theoretically* `SIGINT` does the same than `SIGTERM`, it about to: *give the program itself the opportunity to clean/release resources*.

To be honest after to read many tutorials, I couldn't find and confirm that information explicitly. It for example from:

- [signal(7) — Linux manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)
- [24.2.2 Termination Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)

In many places for these signals are used the *interrupts* and *terminates* terms.

Furthermore, from the same answer exists the *@Jonathan Leffler*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit/4047975#comment4351902_4047975) (extract) as:

> **This is the key point**: `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` can be generated from the terminal using single characters, while the program is running. The other signals have to be generated by another program, somehow (eg by the `kill` command). `SIGINT` is less violent than `SIGQUIT`; the latter produces a *core dump*

Until here as a possible conclusion: `SIGINT` can be triggered through either key combinations or command and `SIGTERM` only by command.

Reason of this post: If *theoretically* `SIGINT` does the same than `SIGTERM`

**Question**

- When is mandatory send `SIGINT` programmatically?

It appears in `kill -l`, so can be use it.

**Extra Questions**

Again, if *theoretically* `SIGINT` does the same than `SIGTERM` - and both can be ignored/blocked/handled

- Why was created `SIGINT`?
- Why <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> was not assigned from the beginning to `SIGTERM`?

To be honest I assumed that `SIGINT` is **not** safe because it *interrupts* the process and therefore would leave some data in a not consistent/integral state

Comment: "Interrupting" (`INT`) a program does not necessarily mean "terminating" (`TERM`) the program. See e.g. how a shell handles the two signals (ignores `TERM` and lets `INT` interrupt a builtin command).

Comment: @ilkkachu _Why do you think SIGINT does the same than SIGTERM only "theoretically"?_ About the _"theoretically"_ - it is based or according with the answer in the post and not according with an official page.

Comment: @Kusalananda agree, but, according with the answer in the other post, both do the same

Comment: To both - in the answer indicates: _"The default action for `SIGINT` **is the same sort of process termination** as the default action for `SIGTERM`"_

Comment: @ilkkachu - right now for more simplicity lets take the question: _Or are you just asking why there are two signals that seem to just do the same thing?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *default action* of both `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` (as well as that of many other signals) is to terminate the process. That's documented in e.g. [the Linux man page `signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), see the table under "Standard signals", quoted in part below. It's quite true in practice too.

Part of the table there:

> ```
>        Signal      Standard   Action   Comment
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>        SIGHUP       P1990      Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
>                                        or death of controlling process
>        SIGINT       P1990      Term    Interrupt from keyboard
>        SIGKILL      P1990      Term    Kill signal
>        SIGTERM      P1990      Term    Termination signal
> ```

Now, that's the **default action**. For most signals, the program receiving them can catch them by setting a signal handler function in advance, or ignore them completely. Knowing that a `SIGINT` is usually sent by a user hitting Ctrl-C, and `SIGTERM` is usually sent by some other program asking the receiving one to exit, a program can decide to deal with them in different ways.

An interactive program might decide to just end any long-running tasks on `SIGINT` instead of exiting immediately, leaving the user the choice to exit or to do something different. All the while still exiting on `SIGTERM`. Then again, a simpler program might set the same handler for both of them (and possibly a few others, like `SIGHUP`): one that saves all data and exits.

As an example, the interactive Bash shell I tried on my Debian clears the current command line on `SIGINT` without executing anything; ignores `SIGTERM` (somewhat surprisingly, but it may have to do with sending signals to whole process groups); and exits on `SIGHUP` (because `SIGHUP` means the terminal connection went away, so there's no point in trying to read further commands).

Most signals allow the receiving process to do any cleanup it likes before (possibly) exiting. The two exceptional signals are `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`, which *can't* be caught or ignored, but they unconditionally and immediately destroy or stop the process, without letting it do any cleanup. (Though note that the kernel would still do any cleanup needed for OS resources, the cleanup here is more about unsaved data in the process memory.)

Of course there are still other signals that also default to terminating the process. Like `SIGALRM`, which is sent by the timer set with the `alarm()` system call. While the default behaviour can be useful in some cases, it's far more useful as a generic alarm clock, e.g. telling the program to do some periodic task.

Comment: Pls consider to add a note to indicate explicitly if is safe trigger `SIGINT` through `ctrl` + `c`

Comment: @ManuelJordan, mhh. Probably the worst that can happen is that the process in question just terminates. But it depends on the program in question, and if it's "safe" for the process to terminate depends on what is meant with "safety" in the context.

Comment: Ok, about _""safety" in the context"_ - I meant leave the data in a consistent way it because the process itself cleaned/released some resources - same as `SIGTERM` does too. - because in the original answer of the other post indicates that `SIGINT` does the same than `SIGTERM` about: _"The default action for SIGINT is the same sort of process termination as the default action for SIGTERM"_ - it was my confusion of the beginning both do a clean/release of resources

Comment: @ManuelJordan, depends on what data there is, and what the program does on receiving the signal. The default action of both `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` **_is_** the same: the termination of the process. Pretty much the same as the program calling `_exit()`. Anything in userspace memory is lost. Any OS resources are handled by the kernel, the same way as always when a program exits. And again that's the _default_: the program can set a signal handler and _do whatever it wants_ when receiving either of those signals.

Comment: @ManuelJordan, if you have a sensible, well-made program, it'll try to keep things in line even if it gets SIGINT or SIGTERM (they're rather common anyway). If the developer has been lazy, they might cause problems. And if the program is insane, it'll run `rm -rf "$HOME"` when getting SIGINT. In general, we don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - again my confusion was in someway why exists `SIGINT` if according with the other answer it does the same as `SIGTERM`: release/clean resources and finally terminate the process - and because each signal uses the `interrupts` and `terminates` terms I assumed that could exists a difference - it of course, it besides that `SIGINT` can be triggered through `Ctrl + C`.

Comment: @ManuelJordan, mm, yeah, signals do interrupt the normal program flow. They can cause system calls to return early (e.g. a `read()` waiting for input can return with `EINTR`, which the program has to deal with), and if there's a signal handler set up, the program will jump to run the handler function immediately, interrupting what ever it was it was doing, and regardless of what that was (a possible source of some issues too, but that's another thing). But it's stuff that the program can be made to deal with, and mostly a headache for the programmer...

Answer (score -1):

> When is mandatory send SIGINT programmatically?

The answer is: never. It is never mandatory to send a signal.
Signals are for catching, not for sending.

> Why was created SIGINT?
> Why ctrl + c was not assigned from the beginning to SIGTERM?

The answer to that lies in the signal codes - SIGINT=2, SIGKILL=9, SIGTERM=15. The SIGINT was created first and assigned to ^C. Then people found, that ^C sometime have to be processed by the application (or can be processed), so the new 'special' SIGKILL was added for use by `kill` tool. Then this signal was caught by many applications and SIGTERM was invented in the hopes that this signal would be uncatchable...

The point is: all signals described in `man 7 signal` as `terminate application` does exactly that - terminate, by default, should terminate, usually terminate... But since an application can catch and process any signal it likes, however it likes - it all become more of a suggestion, than a rule.
Keyword here is "tradition".

Comment: “an application can catch and process any signal it likes, however it likes” — no, some signals can’t be caught.

Comment: _"The SIGINT was created first [...] Then SIGKILL was added"_ -- do you have a source for this piece of history? About the order the signals were added? _"SIGKILL was added for use by kill tool. Then this signal was caught by many applications and SIGTERM was invented in the hopes that this signal would be uncatchable..."_ -- are you sure? Currently `SIGKILL` is the uncatchable one, and `SIGTERM` the regular one.